# Who does A.D.A.M. talk to on the elevator up from the TRO section in Metroid Fusion?

Tags: metroid-fusion

A.D.A.M. has some suspicious conversation with someone on the elevator up from the TRO section in Metroid Fusion, asking if Samus "suspects anything".  Who is the man that he talks to?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Unless I'm remembering incorrectly, it's just some unnamed power back on Earth.  The identity of this person is never actually revealed.  It will make sense, eventually.

Comment: I've beaten the game three times, is it about the secret Metroid facility?

Comment: @JackStone Yes, I'm pretty sure that's what they were referring to.  I've beaten it loads of times.

Comment: It's truly a great game.  That, Zero Mission, and Prime 3 are my favorites, but I like Fusion the most.